# How can I rename a field in django using an input field using Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have an app that allows people to renames files. Issue is I haven't got much idea on how to do this yet.

I want a user to be able to hover over the file of choice, then type in a new file name and then click enter and then that name they enter would rename that file.

[image]

HTML:

```
            {% for video in videos %}
                {% if video.active %}
                    <div class="folder">
                        <div class="folder-settings-tool" onclick="folderSettings(this)">
                            <!-- CHANGE COLOUR OF THE SETTINGS COG TO WHITE -->
                            <img src="{% static 'public/image/icons/settings-work-tool.svg' %}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="folder-settings">
                            <div class="title-change">
                                <p class="title-rename">RENAME</p><input type="text" name="title">
                            </div>
                            <div class="archive">
                                <p class="archive-text">
                                    ARCHIVE
                                </p>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox">
                                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="make-final">
                                <p class="archive-text">
                                    MAKE FINAL
                                </p>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox">
                                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="downloadable">
                                <p class="archive-text">
                                    DOWNLOADABLE
                                </p>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox">
                                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="{% url 'public:file_detail' model='video' pk=video.pk %}">
                            <div class="folder-text">
                                <p>VIDEO</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="{% static 'public/image/icons/folders.svg' %}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="folder-info">
                                <div class="folder-title">   
                                    {{ video.title }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="folder-date">
                                    <p><span class="folder-created">Created</span> {{ video.created }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Models:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='%(class)ss_created', verbose_name = 'project'
    )
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=256)
```

Comment: Each file would have it's own `folder-settings` div right? (I'm basing my assumption on the HTML code posted)

Comment: @Paolo I can add an ID to identify which one I want to rename. But my question is regarding more how I would go about renaming it whether that be in python or javascript?

Comment: Adding ID is the firsts step. One more question, how do you handle state changes on `make final, downloadable and archive`?

Comment: @Paolo Still yet to figure that out. I am implementing the rename first when I can figure out how I can do it

Comment: I suggest you look into AJAX. By mapping event handlers into your HTML elements, you will be able to perform actions you desire.